# AdminLTE plugin when rerouted not working for Cakephp 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frameworks, cakephp-3.7

I m using AdminLTE in my website. But the problem is i have done routing i.e www.mysite.com/admin is my path for admin and this is where i want to render Admin LTE.
So i created a new AppController.php in Admin folder and rendered the AdminLTE in that controller.
But the problem is other features like charts, different layouts and all are not working.

**Here is my routing code**
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);

$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the way You have created new Appcontroller.New Appcontroller should not interfere with the original Appcontroller's functionality.
Refer https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html